# Javascript: change test() method name

Tags: javascript

Okay, I am making a text based game and I have been using the switch command like so

```
switch(true){
case /run/.test(g1):
    prompt("run");
    break;
}
```

the question I have is can I can I change the name of the test() method like so

```
switch(true){
case /run/.act(g1):
    prompt("run");
    break;
}
```

I thought if I created a function like so it would work

```
function act(str){
test(str);
return;
}
```

but it didn't... any help would be nice.

edit: fixed switch statements

Comment: What are you trying to do? `/something/` is a regex object and the same as `new RegExp('/something/')`. Do you want to add your own prototype to the regex object? **Why?**

Comment: Is using `switch` like that actually valid? Should be `switch (value)` AFAIK...

Comment: oh sorry I should have stated that I have the var "g1" calling a text-box on the web page to get the string. then the switch statement is wondering if /something/ is in the string if so it carries on I just want to rename the .test(g1) at the end so it looks like .act(g1) just because every time i read it I feel like I'm calling a test function I made earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `/run/` is a regex object. It has a method called test. It doesn't have a method act, so hence you can't call act() on it.

You'll need to use prototypes:

```
switch{
     case /run/.act(g1):
     prompt("run");
     break;
}
RegExp.prototype.act = function (str) {
    return this.test(str);
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)'s an explanation of Prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** need to do this (please see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) then you can add a [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) to the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object.

```
var regex = /fo+/;
var str = 'fooooooooooooooo';

regex.test(str); //true

RegExp.prototype.act = function(str) {
    if (str == 'fooooooo' && this.test(str)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

regex.act(str); //false (str is not 'fooooooo')
```

Likewise, you can make an alias (but please, don't - it works fine as it is) by simply returning `this.test()`:

```
RegExp.prototype.act = function(str) {
    return this.test(str);
}
```